# (reactjs) Include local Images in react component

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs

I have the following component, which renders an image using html img src=".."

```
export default class Landing extends Component{

  render() {
   return(
     <div className="topimg">
       <img src={'test.jpg'}/>
    </div>
```

But the Page does not display the image. The folder structure is the following

/layout/Landing.jsx
/layour/test.jpg

It works for web urls but not for local files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are building your app but you could attach your images to the component by `require`ing them first. That way the app knows to include the image (referenced relatively from the component) before rendering.

```
export default class Landing extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super(props);

    this.images = {
      test: require('./test.jpg')
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="topimg">
        <img src={this.images.test}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the message that require does not work for test.jpg. Do I miss a step?